# Highest difference between two consecutive prime numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, max, primes

This is a simple program, written in C, which asks user about `int n`.
What's the best way of finding the highest difference between 2 consecutive prime numbers from range from `2` to `n`?

```
int main() {
    int n, i, j, c;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Range To Print Prime Numbers:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Prime Numbers Are Following:\n");
    for(i=1, c=0; i<=n; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
            if (i % j == 0)
                c++;
        if (c == 2)
            printf("%d ", i);
    }

    printf("\n\n The highest difference between numbers is:");

    /* logic i cant get */
    getch();
}
```

Comment: First and last would be of highest difference.

Comment: @haccks I guess there's a missing word "consecutive"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight; I know :)

Comment: You should make your best attempt at writing "the logic you can't get". Otherwise, this exercise would be useless to you.

Comment: `int main`, not `void main`

Comment: Removed the C++ tag since the question says it's C and the code looks like C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the largest difference between two consecutive prime numbers in a variable and if a new difference is larger, replace the variable with the new difference.

```
int maxDifference = 0;
int currentDifference;

// begin looping
currentDifference = calculateNewDifference();

if(currentDifference > maxDifference) {
    maxDifference = currentDifference;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was pseudo-code. It is the difference between the two newest prime numbers.

Comment: If he's struggling with the logic then I don't think efficiency is his greatest concern.